# Extended Stars-and-Bars where the upper bound of a variable is one of the other variables

Tags: combinatorics

How many non-negative integer solutions are there for the equation $x + y + z + w = 20$, where $x>y$.

I started by substituting $x$ for a new variable $x'=x-y$:
$x > y$
$x-y > 0$
$x'>0 $

However, this led me to a point from which I didn't know how to make progress:
$x'+ 2y + z + w = 20$

How should I deal with the $2y$ ?

(the answer provided was $825$)

Comment: I'm not sure one can apply Stars-and-Bars with such modifications.  In general introducing coefficients not equal to one makes the problem (counting non-negative integer solutions) more difficult.  Would you entertain an alternative approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By symmetry, the number of solutions with $x>y$ is the same as the number with $x<y$ so the answer is "half the number of solutions where $x\neq y$."  I would go about this by subtracting the solutions with $x=y$ from the total number of solutions.

Stars and bars gives the total solutions, so now we need to know the number of solutions to $$2x+w+z=20$$ in nonnegative integers.  For a given $x$ this is just $21-2x$ so it's easy to add them up.

Comment: Your logic makes perfect sense. Sadly, I feel it comes back to the problem I encountered in my attempt: not knowing how to make progress with Stars-and-Bars when 2 of the variables are the same.

Comment: @pug - saulspatz is saying this: iterate through $x=0,1,...,10$ and you have $w+z = 20-2x$ which is itself a stars-and-bars problem.  however, this problem is so small ($2$ variables) that the no. of solutions is obviously ${20-2x + 2 -1 \choose 2 - 1} = 21 - 2x$ (he has a typo).  so now you sum through all $x=0,1,...10$ etc

Comment: @antkam Thanks for pointing out the typo.  It's fixed.

Answer (score 2):

$$x+y+z+w=20\tag{1}$$

Firstly it says $x \gt y$ so $x=y+x'+1$ where $x'\ge 0$.

This gives

$$x'+2y+z+w=19\, .$$

So since $2y$ is always *even*, $x'+z+w$ must be *odd* which means either **all three** variables are odd or just **one** is.

1. If **all three** are **odd** then say $x'=2x''+1$, $z=2z''+1$, $w=2w''+1$, giving

\begin{align}&& 2(x''+y+z''+w'')&=16\\[1ex]
&\implies& x''+y+z''+w''&=8\, ,\end{align}

which has $\binom{8+3}{3}$ non-negative integer solutions by bars and stars.

2. If **just one** is **odd**, say $x'=2x''+1$, then the other two must be even: $z=2z''$, $w=2w''$, this gives

\begin{align}&& 2(x''+y+z''+w'')&=18\\[1ex]
&\implies & x''+y+z''+w''&=9\, ,\end{align}

which has $\binom{9+3}{3}$ non-negative integer solutions by bars and stars. However, there are **3** choices for our odd variable so that's $3\binom{9+3}{3}$ total solutions for this case.

Adding both cases together we have a grand total of

$$\binom{8+3}{3}+3\binom{9+3}{3}=825\tag{Answer}$$

non-negative integer solutions to $(1)$ with $x\gt y$.

Comment: A nice approach.  However, the equation $x'' + y + z'' + w'' = 8$ has only $\binom{\color{red}{8} + 3}{3}$ solutions in the nonnegative integers.

Comment: Whoops! Thank you @N.F.Taussig. Where *was* my head when I wrote that? I don't know. I'll edit.